# Parse Int crashes app android

Tags: java, android, parsing, crash, int

I have an editText that i need a user to be able to enter a value. I have the input type set to `android:inputType="number"`. I then get the text from the editText like this:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
String text = editText.getText().toString();
```

I then need to convert this text into an int for comparing to other ints, so I try to parse the int but it crashes my app every time. I have tried many things but it always crashes my app. Any help would be very helpful and thank you in advance.

Comment: What error do you get?
And can you please also post the parsing code?

Comment: Maybe the user isn't writing anything in the field, and "" cant be represented as a number ?

Answer (score 1):

Just get the Integer straight from the editText using this code:

```
int textValue = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
```

and use int textValue for comparing to other ints.

Comment: Thank you for replying but the problem with that is that it says it finds a String but needs an int. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Never mind my problem was that I was passing it to a String still on accident thanks!

Comment: It crashes my app on open. I have no idea what to do

Answer (score 0):

check if your String is null or not and you can also use try and catch if something goes wrong

```
    EditText editText = (EditText)(findViewById(R.id.edt));

    String value = editText.getText().toString();

    if(!value.isEmpty())
    {
        try
        {
            int int_value = Integer.parseInt(value);
        }catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```